css :NOT pseudo-selector not working as required. on <label & text elements
I have an existing WP site, on which there are some forms.   The HTML is formatted as follows:
<div class="frontend-item-container" style="" data-element-key="thumbnail">
     <!-- WPGurus\Forms\Elements\Media_File -->             
     <label for="frontend-form-8-post-data-thumbnail">Featured Image</label>
     This text is used for help text.
     <div class="frontend-item-messages ">
     </div>
     ...

So it has a <div with a class,
Then a <label
Followed by some 'help' text.
And it is the 'help' text that I am trying to select with css.
.frontend-item-container  { color:red; }

selects the <label AND the 'help' text.

.frontend-item-container label { color:red; }

selects just the <label

.frontend-item-container:not(label) { color:red; }

selects the <label AND the 'help' text.    Why does it select the <label????

Is there a css selector that will just select the 'help' text?
Work-around is:
.frontend-item-container * { color:red; }  i.e. to select everything.
then
.frontend-item-container label, ... { color:black; }    to set the label back to original.
But this ... is actually quite a long list of elements.
nb. I'm testing with Chrome.

On posting my Question, I got an automatic answer of:
This question already has answers here:
Is there a CSS selector for text nodes? (3 answers)
However, the 'Answers' are 'experimental' additions to css. And therefore not appropriate for my case.


there is no text selector, none of your selectors is selecting a text node

This code: .frontend-item-container:not(label) { color:red; } is selecting on the parent div itself, so it's actually just matching that as it's :not(label) just like your first example. You need to put a space before the :not() to select children, eg: .frontend-item-container :not(label) { color:red; } however this also won't turn anything red in your example as there's only text directly inside the parent div, and the other div has nothing in it. But if you put some text in a non-label element it will turn it red with that.

it's a bit more nuanced than you stated.. actually .frontend-item-container will just select the container itself.. but since the color property is hinerited from ancestor if not set, such rule will affect all its children (unless being an element with default value for color like an anchor for example). By the way the best solution would be to wrap the text to style in a separate span.. but if you can't, you may style it still with .frontend-item-container and prevent the other elements to be coloured like that using specific rules for them

the point is that an answer would require to better explain how css selectors work and there are many ways to achieve the same desired result.. and using :not is the very last resort in this case

that's actually what you said in your latest workaround... yes exactly! something like that but I would do .container{color: red} and .container *{color:unset;} ... yet there could be some drawbacks with specificity in case there are further rules

I said unset but maybe initial was more appropriate

.frontend-item-container:not(label) { color:red; }
DOES work.    I was missing an "!important" - needed as created by JS.
.frontend-item-container:not(label) { color:red !important; }.       This comment was added before I read the comments above.  I will read them and re-check - thank for your help.


.frontend-item-container:not(label) is exactly the same as .frontend-item-container in you case, the not() part is not needed at all
